# Scale Changes When Knit

Tags: html, r, plot, visualization, scale

I'm trying to create a graph which shows the length of court cases in days at different district courts. I want to standardize the bar heights so that I can fill them based on different types of sentencing (e.g. probation, jail, etc.) and compare the case lengths for different types of sentencing. I'm not sure if the code I have is correct for accomplishing what I want to, but this is the code I'm using:

```
ggplot(plot_one_data, aes(x = length_of_case_in_days, y = sentence_court_name)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = sentence_type), position = "fill") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(
    x = "Relative Length of Case in Days", 
    y = "Sentence Court",
    fill = "Sentence Type"
  )
```

This is the result of that when I run the code in-line in an Rmd:
[plot in Rmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFIRY.png)

When I knit the Rmd, the plot looks like this in the html: [plot in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np6Aw.png)

Obviously, the scale is completely different and the graph is not what I want in the html, which has me questioning if I even have the correct code to accomplish what I want to. Again, I want to standardize the bar heights so I can compare the relative lengths of each type of sentencing case at different district courts. So, I am wondering:

1. Is my code correct for accomplishing this and
2. If so, why does the scale completely change when knit?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included runable code for the rmd.  Make a minimal version, including of your sample data, and post that.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to include a minimal version with sample data? The data set is massive so I'm not sure how to include a usable version here.

Comment: You could manually create a data frame with, say, 10 rows of data that reproduce your error.  Or you could use something like `dput(head(your_data, 10))`.  But reducing your massive data set to something minimal might even show you where the problem is.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example